# Mysql - How to get all records being in other column in the same table

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this (mytable):

```
+------------+-----------+----------------+
| id_mytable | id_artist | foreing_column |
+------------+-----------+----------------+
|          1 |         2 |              5 |
|          2 |         1 |              5 |
|          3 |         1 |              2 |
|          4 |         3 |              6 |
+------------+-----------+----------------+
```

but I only know the number 5 of the column foreign_column, knowing this 5, I can get all the id_artist(in this case 2 and 1)

```
SELECT id_artist FROM `artist_band` WHERE id_band= 5
```

so the problem now is that I want to get the foreign_column of in this case the two id_artist (1 ,2), so I will end up with this table:

```
    +------------+-----------+----------------+
    | id_mytable | id_artist | foreing_column |
    +------------+-----------+----------------+
    |          1 |         2 |              5 |
    |          2 |         1 |              5 |
    |          3 |         1 |              2 |
    +------------+-----------+----------------+
```

(you know all the 2 and all the 1 being in foreign_column)

I've tried something like this:

```
(SELECT id_artist FROM `artist_band` as one WHERE id_band= 5)

inner join

(SELECT * FROM `artist_band` as two )

on one.id_artist = two.id_artist
```

or:

```
SELECT * FROM `artist_band` where id_artist =

(SELECT id_artist FROM `artist_band` WHERE id_band= 5)
```

thanks.

Comment: Try using an IN clause you can supply a list of values from a select statement and then using an IN clause select rows where some value is contained within the result set from the IN clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE id_artist 
IN 
 (
    SELECT id_artist 
    FROM mytable
    WHERE foreign_column = 5 -- (or whatever)
 )
```